# In code session Id and AllowAutoRedirect Not Working. Getting 302

Tags: c#

I'm trying to scrape data from the website in my code below. The site requires that I set a session id to proceed to the second page. I'm trying to extract the session id from the first page and add it as a cookie in the request of the second page but this always returns a 302 error. However if I use a web browser and extract the session id via the developer window and hard code this into the second page request it always works. I've used Fiddler, which generated the below but still no luck in solving this.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response;
            string sessionId = "";
            if (Request_flow_gassco_no(out response))
            {
                StreamReader sReade1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string HTM1 = sReade1.ReadToEnd();
                sessionId = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
                response.Close();
            }

            sessionId = sessionId.Split('=').GetValue(1).ToString().Trim().Split(';').GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
            //s = "4AEEFECB6A59102D0C2F4AC2DBA4362D";

            if (Request_flow_gassco_no_disclaimer(out response, sessionId))
            {
                StreamReader sReade1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string HTM1 = sReade1.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool Request_flow_gassco_no(out HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        response = null;

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://flow.gassco.no/disclaimer");

            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            else return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static bool Request_flow_gassco_no_disclaimer(out HttpWebResponse response, string session)
    {
        response = null;

        try
        {
            Uri target = new Uri("http://flow.gassco.no/");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var cookies = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session) { Domain = target.Host };
            cookieContainer.Add(cookies);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://flow.gassco.no/disclaimer/acceptDisclaimer?");
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", @"1");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
            request.Referer = "http://flow.gassco.no/disclaimer";
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
            request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8");            

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
            else return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (response != null) response.Close();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a difference between a session id returned in a web browser compared to one returned in a httpwebresponse?

Comment: s is the session id returned from the first call to the website.

Comment: s = "JSESSIONID=F287828C5FB022CC833B3C6615ADCA24"

Comment: What are the different constructor parameters to `Cookie`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kesbe27x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if change the cookie code to the below the same issue persists. If I hard code the session id using an id taken from a web browser the second request works. If I use the value returned from first request request.Headers["Set-Cookie"] then it doesn't

session = "4AEEFECB6A59102D0C2F4AC2DBA4362D"
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var cookies = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session) { Domain = target.Host };
cookieContainer.Add(cookies);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this. The steps to get it working were as follows:

1. Make the initial request and extract the cookie from the response. I used a cookie container for this.
2. Make a request to the acceptdisclaimer page. Assigned your cookie container from the first request and also set your request to NOT allow auto redirect.
3. Make a request to the root url again assigning the cookie container. The response returns the expected html.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

What is the value of 's' after this line is executed?

```
s="JSESSIONID="+s.Split('=').GetValue(1).ToString().Trim().Split(';').GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
```

From the looks, I think it will be "JSESSIONID=__utma" which is not what you want.

Comment: s is generated by the site so changes each time i call it. Just run the code now so s = "JSESSIONID=AB608875873C6B188FAFF98D3A157B9D". I've identified that the google analytics __utma etc are not required to proceed to the next page of the site.